# Sandbox loading with many errors net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

After logging in on sandbox.paypal.com, the site is loading with many errors and looks horribly broken.

[image: screenshot]

This seems to be localized to me as my coworkers do not seem to have the same issue, nor have I found any reports of others sharing the same issue.

I'm running OS X Yosemite, and have tried viewing this in Chrome, & Firefox as well as using Incognito mode, but I still get the same thing.

My system is fairly stock with regard to the networking configuration.  I do not have any extra firewall configured that may be blocking these connections.

I have no trouble with the normal live paypal site.

Where to even begin troubleshooting this?  Any help is much appreciated.

## Update

Safari 8.0 (10600.1.25) works.

I was using Chrome Beta (39).  My coworker was using stable and after uninstalling and reinstalling the current stable Chrome 38.0.2125.111, it is now working in Chrome as well.

The current stable version of Firefox 33.0.2 is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like paypall sandbox is broken since 3 days. Before everything was ok, now it serwes 144 empty lines before HTML tag and lost css and other resources.